# Can an amplitude of a wave be $\pi$?

Tags: trigonometry

In the problem I am trying to figure out, the question asks me to find the amplitude of the equation $$y= \pi \sin(5 \pi x).$$

Is the amplitude $\pi$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amplitude is indeed $\pi$. The pre-factor of the trigonometric function dictates the amplitude of the function. For example: in the simpler case
$$ f(x)=a\sin x$$
the amplitude of $f$ is $a$.

Answer (score 1):

the amplitude can be anything. Just multiply it by $x$ to get the same scaling on the amplitude.

in this case $\pi$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the coefficient of the trig expression is its amplitude.